# Configure Ruby/Watir to ignore browser console errors

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, watir

This question relates to automation testing in chrome using Rubymine, Watir and Selenium.

We are getting this console error sometimes which is affecting automation tests via ruby/watir. When the error is present the page does not render and we get a blank page and of course the scenario will time out and fail. When the error is not present the page renders correctly and the scenario will complete.

```
main.8a29c926346b293d1508.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: hj is not defined
    at main.8a29c926346b293d1508.js:1
    at Object.a2P5 (main.8a29c926346b293d1508.js:1)
    at u (runtime.d3b5d5ccc892eb7d0f13.js:1)
    at Object.zUnb (main.8a29c926346b293d1508.js:1)
    at u (runtime.d3b5d5ccc892eb7d0f13.js:1)
    at Object.2 (main.8a29c926346b293d1508.js:1)
    at u (runtime.d3b5d5ccc892eb7d0f13.js:1)
    at t (runtime.d3b5d5ccc892eb7d0f13.js:1)
    at Array.r [as push] (runtime.d3b5d5ccc892eb7d0f13.js:1)
    at main.8a29c926346b293d1508.js:1
```

Does anyone know if there is a switch we can use to ignore console errors and continue to load the page, these are my current options -

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
      options: {"excludeSwitches" => ["enable-automation", "load-extension"]},
      args: ["ignore-certificate-errors", "disable-infobars"]
  )
  options.add_preference(:credentials_enable_service, false)
  options.add_preference(:password_manager_enabled, false)
  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
```

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with your automation. Find out why your application  throws such an error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I agree with you and I am having that argument with others as week speak